# New browser window with JSF primefaces and IE11

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, internet-explorer-11, jsf-2.2

If I open a new browser window with firefox or chrome with an existing login to my application, the new browser window shows the application after the login. So I cannot login with 2 different or more users with firefox for instance. I have read this in other questions and it is clear so far.
But if I open a new window with existing session with IE11, I get an incomplete ui. Also I have to login to my application. If I log in with another or same user does not matter. The ui shows only the background color of the p:layout without any text or link. Why?

Regards
Oliver

Comment: Are you **sure** you have the same session? Do you get any 404's with loading stylesheets? Is IE running in compatibility mode? Are you using PrimeFaces 2.0?

Comment: I am using JSF 2.2.10 with Primefaces 5.2.6. I get no errors or exceptions. I am not sure if it is the same session, because IE11 shows the login screen and FF and chrome does not.

Comment: I would say that if you get a login screen on the second tab,it is **not** the same session

Comment: Maybe. I am just wondering if I login with FF and chrome for instance both instances work. With 2 IE11 windows it shows the 2nd how described.

Comment: Yes and? Try to look up information on the internet on how new windows behave session wise across different browsers.